# have an admin & user routing structure in angular

Tags: angular

I want to create an angular app with 2 separate modules for Admin panel and the site's front-end which I use lazy-loading for modules. Now I want to don't show header and footer components when user goes to /admin route , here is my code:

**app.component.html**

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

and here is my project structure:

```
app
  - admin
    -login component
    -dashboard component
    -admin.module
    -admin.routing.module
    -...
  - pages
    -home component
    -products component
    -...
  - shared
  app.component
  app.module
  app.routing.module
...
```

Can you assist me what should I do? what is the best practice?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create nested routes for reuse the layout frame for admin and  website routes and avoiding to apply rules to show or hide layout elements.

Try something like this:

app-routing.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'admin',
    component: AdminComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'users',
        component: UsersComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard],
      },
      // <-- place here others admin/private routes
    ],    
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: WebsiteComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'products',
        loadChildren: () => import('./products/products.module').then((m) => m.ProductsModule),
      },  
      // <-- place here others lazy loaded site/public routes
    ],        
  },
];
```

app.component.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

admin.component.html:

```
<app-admin-header></app-admin-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-admin-footer></app-admin-footer>
```

In this way `/admin/users` and all other admin child routes with have the admin `header` and `footer`.

website.component.html:

```
<app-website-header></app-website-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-website-footer></app-website-footer>
```

and `/products` and all other website child routes with have the website `header` and `footer`.

I hope it will help, try it and enjoy!

Comment: I wanna have 2 separate layouts, first one for the frontend and second one for admin panel . In first one I have header and footer and in second one just have a router-outlet

Comment: Our app uses a service with some behaviorsubjects to determine whether the header and footer shows. We use a router interceptor to check a list of routes, and if it's one of the special routes we hide them, otherwise we show them

Comment: though by default we have it so they do not show, that way iframes are handled well

Answer (score 0):

Finally I find this on StackOverFlow and I think this is a simple solution for my issue.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multi-layout-example

Comment: this link is not working anymore